# Multi variables limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I solve a limit for two variables $$\displaystyle\lim_{x,y\to\infty}\dfrac{(xy)^{x^2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{x^2}}?$$

I don't know how to avoid having indetermination

Comment: What does $\lim_{x,y \to \infty}$ mean?

Answer (score 4):

Using the well-known inequality: $\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$, this implies the limit to be $0$.